# Debugging two glassfish domains in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, glassfish-3

I have two glassfish domain, one front and on backend. I have set up to server adapters in eclipse. On one of he domains I have changed the debug port number to 9008 to avoid conflict.

When starting up in debug mode, the one using the default port number 9009 is working fine, when starting the one with 9008 I get Connection refused.

I guess its because eclipse is trying to connect to the 9009 port insteed of 9008.
Do you think this is right? In that case how can I change what port Eclipse is connecting to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this is a bug in the eclipse glassfish plugin. The plugin is hardcoded to connect to port 9009

http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISHPLUGINS-358